# How to get better image quality when taking photos using Camera API?

Tags: android, android-camera

I intend to take some photos using the Camera API. I have got the code running but the image quality is quite poor. Here is the code I use:

```
Camera.Parameters params = c.getParameters();
c.setParameters(params);
Camera.Parameters p = c.getParameters();

final List<Size> listSize = p.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
Size mPreviewSize = listSize.get(2);

p.setPreviewSize(1280, 720); // I
p.setPictureSize(1280, 720); // II
p.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.NV21);
c.setParameters(p);
SurfaceView view = sv;
try {
        c.setPreviewDisplay(view.getHolder());
        c.startPreview();
} catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
}

c.takePicture(null, null, null, new PicClick(this)); //PictureCallback
```

I thought I could increase photo quality using (I) and (II), but it doesn't seem to work. Are there any other parameters I could change?

Comment: "image quality" is a $1M question. Picture size is the only, and not the most important factor for photo quality. You need to choose the correct focus; you want to tune exposure to fit the scene. Most importantly, you quality of a photo requires a good photographer to choose what picture to take, and she will know how her tools (hardware and software) can deliver maximum.

Comment: As a side note, you should not hardcode the size: not every device even supports 1280x720 preview or photo. Using `listSize.get(2)` is no good, either: while you can expect the list of supported preview sizes be at least 3 items long, you have no guarantee that item at (2) is better than (0) or (5).

Comment: @AlexCohn So I need to add focus and exposure. How can I do that programmatically?

Comment: The Camera API is described on the Android Developers site, and in many books and online tutorials, but if the question is *"how to choose the best parameters programmatically?"*, the answer is ***it's hard***. I would suggest to use the camera intent instead of reinventing everything: on each device, huge engineering effort is made to produce best pictures, and all this is built in the stock Camera app. Or, the end-users may install the camera app of their choice, if they want to achieve some special effect.